# Authentication Success Handler for pre-authenticated scenario

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am looking for a way to add some custom code right when the user is pre-authenticated from a Java EE container (using Kerberos). I am using Spring Security for authorization, which works very well. But now I want to be able to detect if the current user exists in the database using a simple Spring service (and then repository) method.

My SecurityConfig.java file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/rest/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/static/jsp/logout.jsp")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll()

        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/login","/accessDenied", "/resources/**", "/static/*").permitAll()

            .antMatchers("/security/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and().anonymous().disable()

         .jee()

            .mappableRoles("USER","ADMIN");
}
```

}

My stack:

- JBoss 7.2
- Spring MVC 4.0.6
- Spring Security 3.2.4

Any example or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to check if user authenticated and exist in database?

Comment: Well, I would like to get my logic invoked right after the user is pre-authenticated (as soon as Spring Security knows it is authenticated from the container), and then I would do my checks : if user record does not exist in database, create it based on details from LDAP. If exists, load it from database and update last login timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may implement your AuthenticatioSuccessHandler like this

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth == null && auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            String username = auth.getPrincipal().toString();
            UserData userData = userService.getUserData(username);
            // And then here more checks, handlings etc.
        }


        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }

}
```

And register it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I already tried that route but the method is never being invoked. I have added a breakpoint and a sysout and unfortunately it is not triggering...

Comment: Probably you didn't register it properly. Your configuration way is a bit different to my current xml based configuration. I will try it at home and hopefully let you inform how to register the success handler properly.

Comment: Yes I am using Java Config but I can convert XML configuration pretty easily.

Comment: I added a custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter with <custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthenticationFilter" /> which is similar to addFilterAfter method of HttpSecurity class (or you may use only addFilter. And inject to this filter myAuthenticationSuccessHandler. // You probably don't need UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter because you use Kerberos for authentication. I'm not sure how do you combine Kerberos authentication and Spring security.

Comment: Another option that I thought about is to develop an aspect on the "getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal" method located in the org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter class 

I can see "PreAuthenticated J2EE principal: my user id" every time I log in the application. 

Would it be a good option?

Comment: I use Spring Security only for authorization purpose. I got roles defined in web.xml and jboss-web.xml, which are mapped to Spring Security granted authorities once the user is authenticated from JBoss via Active Directory.

JBoss also provides all groups from Active Directory to which the current user is member of.

Comment: Then probably it's not necessary to implement a success handler. Try to implement a Filter which use J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter and add this filter using addFilter method. So everytime when this filter is called you can check if preAuthenticatedPrincipal exist in database and do some handling according to it. I'm not really sure about this because i did't used J2EEPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter before.

Comment: I wonder if it is actually feasible to add custom logic on top of an existing filter from the Spring Security filter chain (J2EEPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter in my case)?

Comment: Actually maybe there is a cleaner way to do it. I think, you can create an independent filter, which contains a similar logic to MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler (see above example) Only difference is, you have to put the logic in doFilter() method. And register this filter via addFilterAfter(myFilter, J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class). So everytime after J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter executed, your custom filter will be called and you can do your custom checks.

Comment: Custom filter works. The only issue I got is that it is invoked on any single request. I guess I could just check if my current user object is in session, or find any other way to restrict its execution only once.